# How to put buttons on navbar,not on collapse

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need a button in the navbar with a red frame which should not collapse. The above image shows how I want button to look like. Thanks in advance who are going to help.

image url:https://imgur.com/gallery/NhelOqP

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<div class="row col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 p-0">
  <div class="col-6 col-sm-7 col-md-9 col-lg-2">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> gg3b0</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-lg-8 justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
<div class="nav col-6 col-sm-5 col-md-3 col-lg-2 justify-content-end">
            <button type="button" name="button">
              <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/download-instagram-png-logo-20.png" width="40" height="40" alt="">
            </button>
            <button type="button" name="button">
              <img src="https://cdn.clipart.email/effa61884fa5c47f266cf2b3a9b9a7b8_avatar-user-profile-male-logo-profile-icon-png-pngwave_910-912.png" width="40" height="40" alt="">
            </button>
          </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  
 
          
           <form class="form-inline my-1">
    <div class="md-form form-sm my-0">
     <button class="navbar-toggle my-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  

            <button type="button" name="button" class="border border-danger">
              <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/instagram-logos-png-images-free-download-2.png" width="40" height="40" alt="">
            </button>
            <button type="button" name="button" class="border border-danger">
              <img src="https://cdn.clipart.email/effa61884fa5c47f266cf2b3a9b9a7b8_avatar-user-profile-male-logo-profile-icon-png-pngwave_910-912.png" width="40" height="40" alt="">
            </button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```